# How to lock one activities orientation,then have another on top which is free to rotate?

Tags: java, android, orientation

I am developing an app for Android where I use the front camera as a mirror and have controls on top to do various functions. Now I was wondering how I can get the MainActivity to stay locked as 'portrait' and have another activity on top (which has all the buttons and has a transparent background) to have freedom to rotate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So you have two activites, one for which orientation is fixed and another one is free to rotate.
For the activity for which orientation is to be fixed, add this line in its activity tag in Manifest.xml :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyPreferencesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

And by default the other activity is free to rotate.Mark the answer as verified if it works.

The above way is static (defined in xml).Ii  it doesn't work, try this programmatical(can be changed during runtime) method also:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that doesn't work. When i add that line, every Activity becomes locked in that orientation.

Comment: Did you add the line in manifest , or somewhere else(I forgot to mention that).??  Just now checked,it works for me.

Comment: i did add the line to my Manifest and also tried the programmatic way but no luck, wherever i lock the orientation every Activity obeys it. I've even tried individually locking each Activity in a different orientation but they all seem to following the lowest line in the Manifest file

Comment: Please create a new project with two actvities (With no added content than functions added by studio) and check in that.If that works,Share your project code.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, is there any min API Level?

Comment: Not sure about required minimum,i am using 15 as minimum and it works fine

Comment: Ok so i made a new project (with api level 20) that has two activities, the main activity loads and start an intent to start the other one,on the second activity i put a tranparent theme on to see through to the main activity. on the main activity it loads in Landscape and i put a button to change and lock the orentatin to portrait when the app loads it loads both in landscape and when i press the button they both move to portrait, so i dont think this works As for th source code im not sure how to upload it.